# Video length is different from starting and ending time stamp in MediaCodec

Tags: java, video, mp4, frame-rate, android-mediacodec

I have a legacy code written by someone else and I just recently realised that the video recorded in the app has different length when it is played outside the app or programmatically checked using `MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION` than the measured time using the frames' timeStamps.

The difference is almost 20% longer video than measured.

Below is the printout from the frame timestamps:

```
frameRate: 30                                
estimateStarttime: 83990376186060            
estimateEndTime: 84009908074060
```

Which translates to 19.53 seconds while results from the MediaPlayer and `MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION`

```
duration player for Example-video is 23520
duration flag for Example-video is 23520
```

And here is a snippet of my code:

```
final ArrayList<Surface> als = new ArrayList<>();
        final Surface is;

        Range<Integer> targetFps = null;
        Range<Integer>[] ranges = targetDetails.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES);
        if(ranges != null)
            for (Range<Integer> range : ranges) {
                //Request the highest available lower==upper fps range.
                Log.d("FPSRangeMeta", String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "(%dx%d): [%d..%d]", 1280, 720, range.getLower(), range.getUpper()));
                if(range.getUpper().equals(range.getLower())){
                        if(targetFps == null)
                            targetFps = range;
                        if(range.getLower() > targetFps.getLower())
                            targetFps = range;
                    }
            }


        //noinspection ConstantConditions targetFps to be implemented
        final int framerate =  targetFps != null?targetFps.getLower():15;
        System.out.println("frameRate: " + framerate);
        if (recording) {
            MediaCodec.Callback cb = new MediaCodec.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onInputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec mc, int inputBufferId) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Shouldn't be called with an input surface.");
                }


                @SuppressLint("LogConditional")
                @Override
                public void onOutputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec codec, int index, @NonNull MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
                    try {
                        ByteBuffer outputBuffer = Objects.requireNonNull(codec.getOutputBuffer(index));
                        //codec.getOutputFormat(index); // option A

                        synchronized (CameraHandler.this) {
                            long flags = info.flags;
                            if(estimateTimestamp == 0 && estimateStarttime != 0) {
                                estimateTimestamp = estimateStarttime;
                                System.out.println("estimateStarttime: " + estimateStarttime);
                            }
                            encodedFrameCallback.pushFrameMeta("frame.keyframe", frameIndex, flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME);
                            encodedFrameCallback.pushFrameMeta("frame.output_time_info", frameIndex, info.presentationTimeUs*1000);
                            encodedFrameCallback.pushFrameMeta("frame.frame_delta", frameIndex, info.presentationTimeUs*1000 - prev);
                            if(prev != 0){
                                estimateTimestamp += info.presentationTimeUs*1000 - prev;
                            }
                            encodedFrameCallback.pushFrameMeta("frame.estimated_timestamp", frameIndex, estimateTimestamp);
                            encodedFrameCallback.pushH264Frame(outputBuffer, info.offset, info.size, info.presentationTimeUs);
                            prev = info.presentationTimeUs*1000;
                            frameIndex++;
                        }
                        codec.releaseOutputBuffer(index, false);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Timber.e(e);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull MediaCodec codec, @NonNull MediaCodec.CodecException e) {
                    Log.d("MCError", "MediaCodec error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onOutputFormatChanged(@NonNull MediaCodec mc, @NonNull MediaFormat format) {
                }
            };

            //noinspection HardCodedStringLiteral
            MediaFormat mf = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 720);

            Range<Integer> complexityRange = codec.getCodecInfo().getCapabilitiesForType("video/avc").getEncoderCapabilities().getComplexityRange();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                Range<Integer> qualityRange = codec.getCodecInfo().getCapabilitiesForType("video/avc").getEncoderCapabilities().getQualityRange();
                Log.d("CameraHandler", "Available quality range: "+qualityRange.getLower()+" --- "+qualityRange.getUpper());
                if(!qualityRange.getLower().equals(qualityRange.getUpper())) mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_QUALITY, qualityRange.getUpper());
            } else  {
                Log.d("CameraHandler", "Can't set quality, Android version too low");
            }

            MediaCodecInfo.EncoderCapabilities ec = codec.getCodecInfo().getCapabilitiesForType("video/avc").getEncoderCapabilities();
            Log.d("CameraHandler", "CBR:" + ec.isBitrateModeSupported(MediaCodecInfo.EncoderCapabilities.BITRATE_MODE_CBR));
            Log.d("CameraHandler", "CQ:" + ec.isBitrateModeSupported(MediaCodecInfo.EncoderCapabilities.BITRATE_MODE_CQ));
            Log.d("CameraHandler", "VBR:" + ec.isBitrateModeSupported(MediaCodecInfo.EncoderCapabilities.BITRATE_MODE_VBR));

            Log.d("CameraHandler", "Available complexity range: "+complexityRange.getLower()+" --- "+complexityRange.getUpper());


            mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
            mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 12140318);//Same as sample file from Xperia Z5 recording.
            mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, framerate);
            mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CAPTURE_RATE, framerate);
            mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_PRIORITY, 0);
            mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
            mf.setLong(MediaFormat.KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER, 100000000);


            mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileHigh);
            mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_LEVEL, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCLevel41);
            try {
                codec.reset();
                codec.setCallback(cb);
                codec.configure(mf, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            } catch(Exception failed_hi41){

                mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileHigh);
                mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_LEVEL, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCLevel31);
                failed_hi41.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    codec.reset();
                    codec.setCallback(cb);
                    codec.configure(mf, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
                } catch(Exception failed_hi31){
                    mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileMain);
                    mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_LEVEL, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCLevel31);
                    codec.reset();
                    codec.setCallback(cb);
                    codec.configure(mf, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
                }

            }

            is = codec.createInputSurface();

            als.add(is);
        }

        boolean finalUseMotionTrack = useMotionTrack;
        Range<Integer> finalTargetFps = targetFps;
        CameraDevice.StateCallback cameraCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(@NonNull final CameraDevice camera) {
                currentCamera = camera;

                if(closed) return;

                try {
                    if (dicb != null)
                        dicb.deviceInfo(
                            codec.getOutputFormat(),
                            camera,
                            framerate,
                            cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(camera.getId()));

                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {

                    final CaptureRequest.Builder cr = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);

                    //Use control mode AUTO so we can access A3 features.
                    cr.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

                    //Use standard video-oriented auto focus - since some devices can't live without it...
                    cr.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);

                    //Use standard white balance optimization
                    cr.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO);

                    //Enable auto exposure. This is not ideal, but manual configuration is hard over multiple devices.
                    cr.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
                    if(finalTargetFps != null) cr.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, finalTargetFps);

                    //Request widest available field of view
                    float focalLengths[] = targetDetails.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS);
                    if(focalLengths != null && focalLengths.length > 0)
                        cr.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCAL_LENGTH, focalLengths[0]);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P && finalUseMotionTrack) {
                        cr.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT_MOTION_TRACKING);
                    } else {
                        cr.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT_VIDEO_RECORD);
                    }

                    cr.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF);
                    cr.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                        cr.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_OIS_DATA_MODE, CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_OIS_DATA_MODE_OFF);
                    }

                    for (Surface al : als) {
                        cr.addTarget(al);
                    }

                    CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback sessionCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            if(closed) return;
                            if (recording) codec.start();
                            try {
                                CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback cc = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                                        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                                        long frame = result.getFrameNumber();
                                        if(estimateStarttime == 0){
                                            Long ts = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_TIMESTAMP);
                                            estimateStarttime = ts!=null?ts:0;
                                        }
                                        Long timestamp = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_TIMESTAMP);
                                        Long exposuretime = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME);
                                        Long shutterskew = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_ROLLING_SHUTTER_SKEW);
                                        Long frameduration = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION);

                                        Long clock_timing_monotonic = System.nanoTime();
                                        Long clock_timing_realtime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
                                        Long clock_timing_millis = System.currentTimeMillis();


                                        if(encodedFrameCallback != null){
                                            encodedFrameCallback.pushFrameMeta("comparable.realtime_time", frame, clock_timing_realtime);
                                            encodedFrameCallback.pushFrameMeta("comparable.monotonic_time", frame, clock_timing_monotonic);
                                            encodedFrameCallback.pushFrameMeta("comparable.millis_time", frame, clock_timing_millis);

                                            if(timestamp != null) encodedFrameCallback.pushFrameMeta("sensor.timestamp", frame, timestamp);
                                            if(exposuretime != null) encodedFrameCallback.pushFrameMeta("sensor.exposure_time", frame, exposuretime);
                                            if(shutterskew != null) encodedFrameCallback.pushFrameMeta("sensor.rolling_shutter_skew", frame, shutterskew);
                                            if(frameduration != null) encodedFrameCallback.pushFrameMeta("sensor.frame_duration", frame, frameduration);
                                        }
                                    }

                                };
                                if(closed) return;
                                Handler h = new Handler(captureLooperThread.getLooper());
                                //if(finalSc != null) finalSc.setCaptureCallback(cc, h);
                                session.setRepeatingRequest(cr.build(), cc, h);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException | IllegalStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                onFailure.run();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            Timber.e("onConfigureFailed", new Exception("Failed to configure camera??"));
                            onFailure.run();
                        }
                    };

                    camera.createCaptureSession(als, sessionCallback, new Handler(recordLooperThread.getLooper()));
                } catch (CameraAccessException | IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    onFailure.run();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) { }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
                Timber.e("Camera error "+error, new Exception("Got a camera error, "+error));
            }
        };

        cameraManager.openCamera(targetCamera, cameraCallback, new Handler(stateLooperThread.getLooper()));
        return true;
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
public void stopRecording(){
    closed = true;
    if(currentCamera != null) currentCamera.close();
    currentCamera = null;
    System.out.println("estimateEndTime: " + estimateTimestamp);

    codec.stop();
    codec.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deeper into my code I found that the problem is not with the MediaCode settings/configurations. But the problem was in storing the file as you can see below:

```
data.position(offset);
data.limit(offset + size);//This causes the stored video to be longer than it is in reality. 
        try {
            while (data.remaining() > 0)
                h264Stream.getChannel().write(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {}
```

removing the line `data.limit(offset + size);` fixed my problem.
The offset is

> The start-offset of the data in the buffer.

And the size is

> The amount of data (in bytes) in the buffer. If this is 0, the buffer has no data in it and can be discarded. The only use of a 0-size buffer is to carry the end-of-stream marker.

I still don't understand the repercussions of removing that line but I am going to do extensive tests.
Please drop comments or a better answer if you have knowledge about it. I will change the correct answer!